# How do I set an onClickListener for a bitmap? android java

Tags: java, android, bitmap, onclick, onclicklistener

Is it possible to set an onClickListener for a bitmap while programming an Android app in java?  I tried using the same code as a button but eclipse displayed an error that a bitmap was not valid.  Please provide example code with your answer if it is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `ImageButton` and set it the bitmap with [`setImageBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29). Then just set a listener to the `ImageButton` object.

```
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
imgButton.setImageBitmap(myBitmapObject);
imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){    
     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "ImageButton Pressed", 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        });
```

Comment: Is it possible to draw it to a specific point on the screen like a bitmap?

Comment: You could move your `imgButton` anywhere in the screen using an adapted layout, but i'm not sure if I understood you well